# Can you inspect your own vehicle in Texas?

Tags: texas, vehicle, motor-vehicle, vehicle-registration, automotive

In Texas, with the proper licensing and training, is it possible to inspect one's own vehicle?

https://www.dps.texas.gov/section/vehicle-inspection/inspector-qualifications-and-training

Comment: I suspect strongly that this is not permitted in practice even if the bar provisions of the regulations don't expressly rule it out, on common law conflict of interest grounds if not otherwise prohibited by statute or regulation.

Comment: It is possible to inspect your vehicle without being trained and licensed to do so.  I do it before long road trips.

Comment: I suspect the answer to that is in the certification.

Comment: @MichaelHall: I think the question is whether you can perform an inspection on your vehicle that will satisfy the compulsory inspection requirement of [Transportation Code Chapter 548](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/TN/htm/TN.548.htm).

Comment: @NateEldredge, Although I didn't take the time to research the specific code the OP might have been asking about, I would agree.  My lightly sarcastic comment was geared towards improving the question per your comment;  i.e. "is it legal to certify..." vs "can I inspect".  (the answer to "can I" is usually "IDK, are you able to?")